# Using grepl to delete rows in dataframe R - Methodological Question

Tags: r, grepl

I have used `grepl` as follows in two cases:

First method:

```
rc_area <- rc_area[!grepl("Avg",rc_area$Year),]
```

Second method:

```
library(dplyr)
rc_area <- rc_area %>% filter(!(grepl("Avg", rc_area$Year)))
```

The first method executes without any error and is understable to me. However, the second method gives the following error.

`Error in env_bind_lazy(private$bindings, !!!set_names(promises, names_bindings)) :  attempt to use zero-length variable name`

I am unable to understand what is the problem in the second one.

Here is the data in request.

```
structure(list(Year = c("1993-94", "1994-95", "2-Years'Avg:", 
"1995-96", "1996-97", "1997-98", "1998-99", "1999-00", "5-Years'Avg:", 
"2000-01", "2001-02", "2002-03", "2003-04", "2004-05", "5-Years'Avg:", 
"2005-06", "2006-07", "2007-08", "2008-09", "2009-10", "5-Years'Avg:", 
"2010-11"), Punjab = c("1300.6", "1338.7", "1319.7", "1327.8", 
"1354.5", "1409.9", "1492.9", "1609.4", "1438.9", "1627.2", "1475.9", 
"1512.3", "1687.9", "1754.3", "1611.5", "1762.4", "1728.4", "1723.5", 
"1977.7", "1931.5", "1824.7", "1766.8"), Sindh = c("702.9", "598.3", 
"650.6", "642.3", "701.8", "689.3", "704.1", "690.4", "685.6", 
"540.1", "461.1", "488.3", "551.2", "543.9", "516.9", "593.2", 
"598.1", "594.0", "733.5", "707.7", "645.3", "361.2"), KPK = c("62.7", 
"63.3", "63.0", "63.7", "64.7", "66.8", "68.2", "67.1", "66.1", 
"66.4", "60.7", "61.0", "61.7", "59.9", "61.9", "59.4", "60.8", 
"61.7", "61.3", "53.8", "59.4", "46.1"), c("", "", "", "", "", 
"", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", 
""), Balochistan = c("120.9", "124.3", "122.6", "128.0", "130.1", 
"151.3", "158.4", "148.5", "143.2", "142.9", "116.5", "163.6", 
"159.8", "161.5", "148.9", "206.4", "193.9", "136.2", "190.1", 
"190.1", "183.3", "191.2"), Pakistan = c("2187.1", "2124.6", 
"2155.9", "2161.8", "2251.1", "2317.3", "2423.6", "2515.4", "2333.8", 
"2376.6", "2114.2", "2225.2", "2460.6", "2519.6", "2339.2", "2621.4", 
"2581.2", "2515.4", "2962.6", "2883.1", "2712.7", "2365.3")), row.names = c(NA, 
22L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible sample of your data please.

Comment: I think one of the columns is blank and that seems to be creating this error. After removing empty column as `rc_area[5] <- NULL` method 2 works fine.

Comment: OK - if you solved your own problem you should write it as an answer an accept it to help other poeple with the same issue.

Comment: But then it is useful to see that `dplyr` has issues with empty columns, while the first method can handle even empty columns too.

Comment: Mine is not an answer technically because still I am not clear why method 1 worked and method 2 didn't. It is just a fault finding exercise. A better explanation is still awaited.